# Is There Any method To construct/Take 1 cm reading to compass without a scale and only using compass.

Tags: geometry, circles, geometric-construction

Hi sorry if I asked this Q but I was wondering was there any method to take 1 cm or any reading to the compass(without the help of ruler) by just using compass itself/properties of circles.Sorry ones again.

Comment: You want to construct a 1cm line but with no distance reference?  Since the definition of the metre is totally arbitrary, this seems very unlikely.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr%E2%80%93Mascheroni_theorem

Comment: Sir thanks for this link.